# SASS - Refer scss files into main.scss file to change main.css

Tags: html, css, sass

I am using SASS and I have different scss files which describes the layout on my webpage, like my ***_navbar.scss*** and ***_footer.scss*** file (also have the ***main.scss*** file without underscore).

Now I want to refer all my layout scss files to my main.scss so that my main.css will get the styles for everything which is refered in the main.scss file. Do someone know how to do this since @import is not used anymore? Do I need some extensions or tools?

Here is the HTML code.

```html
<section class="navbar" id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="linkbox">Test</a></li>
                <li><a class="linkbox">Test</a></li>
                <li><a class="linkbox">Test</a></li>
                <li><a class="linkbox">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
    </section>


    <section class="footer">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="header">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Here is my folder structure.
[Folder strucure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9FGY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! `@import` still works and you should still use that. Read the `Heads Up` section: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Answer (score 0):

Check out @use.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

The @use rule loads mixins, functions, and variables from other Sass stylesheets, and combines CSS from multiple stylesheets together. Stylesheets loaded by @use are called "modules". Sass also provides built-in modules full of useful functions.

Comment: A major caveat to `@use` is that it is only supported by `dart-sass`. If OP is using npm (libsass) or rubysass, `@use` will throw errors and will not compile. Read the `Heads up` section: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import